# Expanding a frequency table in dplyr that is grouped by weeks into days, and fill the according values correctly

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have a frequency table in R, that has 12 different columns A:L, and a date by week column `format = "%Y-%m-%d". There are 52/53 rows for the past year. Due to the calculations I need to do. I am looking to expand the rows into single day observations and just simply divide every row value (A:L) by 7 into equal observations for every 7 day period.

I am currently using expand to create a date column for every day we are looking to include, but I cannot get the data to fill in for the multiple columns and scale itself for its according date range

```
df %>%
  expand(Date = seq(from = as.Date(first_of_this_month_last_year) , to = as.Date(first_of_this_month_this_year), by="day"), [HAVE TRIED MANY DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS HERE BUT NOTHING HAS WORKED])
```

Current Table :

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 | 75 | 21 |
| 2022-01-11 | 18 | 17 |

Desired Output Table :

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-06 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-07 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-08 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-09 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-10 | 10.7 | 3 |
| 2022-01-11 | 2.5 | 2.4 |

In the actual input and output table we have 12 columns of observations and 1 date column, and we want to expand the 52 rows of weeks into 365 days of equal observations. So I am looking for a generic formula/solution to apply across multiple rows and a far larger dataset than the one shown above.

I am still young in developing my dplyr and R cleaning and formatting skills, so any and all help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: It will help if you can provide some sample data to test on, but after you expand (and leave a lot of zeros) you might try something like `group_by(week(Date)) %>% mutate(across(c(<cols to divide>), ~ first(.) / 7)`

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by building each day of the week separately and then stacking them all together. Something like this:

```r
table_0d = df %>%
  mutate(A = A/7, B = B/7, ...)

table_1d = table_0d %>% mutate(Date = Date + 1)
table_2d = table_0d %>% mutate(Date = Date + 2)
table_3d = table_0d %>% mutate(Date = Date + 3)
...
table_6d = table_0d %>% mutate(Date = Date + 6)

output_df = rbind(table_0d, table_1d, table_2d, ... table_6d) %>%
  arrange(Date)
```

Comment: This is a great approach, it is not exactly how I was thinking about the problem. But it definitely works ! Thank you